# AWS cloudwatch agent multiline logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a problem with java logs that are output in several lines as stacktrace. The logs are as follows in the logfile:

```
[INFO ][168077] 14.12.2023 09:00:46.595 [http-nio-5000-exec-23] xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  xxxxxx {"xxx":"xxx","xxx":"xx","xx":0,"xx":20,"xx":"xxx","year":0,"xxx":0,"xxx":false,"xxx":false}
[ERROR][168077] 14.12.2023 09:00:48.798 [http-nio-5000-exec-19] org.apache.juli.logging.xxxx xxx - Servlet.service() for servlet [xxxx] in context with path [] threw exception
xxxxxxxxxx: 400 : "{"error":"xxxxx","error_description":"xxxxxx"}"
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.xxxx.xxxxx(xxxx.java:132) ~[xxxxxxxx]
--
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:714) ~[xxxxxxxx]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.introspection.SpringOpaqueTokenIntrospector.xxxx(xxxxx.java:146) ~[xxxxxx]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.introspection.SpringOpaqueTokenIntrospector.introspect(xxxxxxx.java:128) ~[xxxxxx]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.OpaqueTokenAuthenticationProvider.xxx(xxxxx.java:125) ~[xxxxxx]
    ... 55 more
```

my configuration of the cloudwatch agent looks like this:

```
{
    "agent": {
            "run_as_user": "xxx-xxx"
    },
    "logs": {
            "logs_collected": {
                    "files": {
                            "collect_list": [
                                    {
                                            "file_path": "/var/log/nginx/xxx.log",
                                            "log_group_name": "xxxx",
                                            "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}",
                                            "retention_in_days": -1,
                                            "multi_line_start_pattern": "\[[A-Z]+\s?\]"

                                    }
                            ]
                    }
            }
    }
```

}

The regex should get the start of line [INFO ] ... and [ERROR] with [[A-Z]+\s?]

unfortunately no more logs arrive in cloudwatch when I add the line with multiline-start-pattern. I'm not sure if it's the regex or just the config. The docs at aws are a bit poor on this topic.